# Calculate probabilities from distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ be a RV with the following distribution function

- $F(x)=0$, if $x<0$
- $F(x)=x/4$, if $0 \le x<1$
- $F(x)=1/2+(x-1)/4$, if $1\le x<2$
- $F(x)=11/12$, if $2\le x<3$
- $F(x)=1$, if $x \ge 3$.

Calculate $P(1 \le X \le 2.5)$.

The answer key given in class does this as $F(2.5)-F(1-)=11/12-1/4=2/3$.

But shouldn't it be $F(2.5)-F(1)=11/12-(1/2+(1-1)/4)=5/12$?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the possibility that $X=1$, which you don't if what you subtract is $F(1)=P(X\leq1)$. It doesn't make a difference for continuous distribution functions, but this time it does.

Comment: Here the value of x should be greater than 1, but we are taking the function for x<1, as F(1-). Can you elaborate a bit more? I am new to this.

Comment: You were asked to calculate the probability that $1\leq X\leq 2.5$. By definition, $F(x)=P(X\leq x)$, so what you did was$$F(2.5)-F(1)=P(X\leq 2.5)-P(X\leq 1)=P(1<X\leq 2.5)$$This is not what you're asked to calculate, and it is why you get the wrong result. What they did instead was to use $F(x^-)=P(X<x)$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for clarifying